# How do the Java API classes do such specific things?

Tags: java, api

I'm very new to java, and ever since I started learning it, I have always wondered: The classes and packages of the java API do many useful things, from creating windows to writing to files. But at the beginning, the API classes use nothing but the language to do whatever they do.

I know that with the language, you can store data in variables, perform logic, create methods, objects, and classes, and so on. But to do all the "good stuff", you use the API classes. But how can they do such cool things with just the language? Does the code built in to java specify how to create windows or write to files? And how can you use the code to output information to external things, like motors?

It seems like the code built in can't handle the things that the API can do all by itself, but the API is written in java, and therefore uses the raw language to do the things that it does.

I think I've made my point, but how does that all work?

Comment: While it's true that a large part of Java API is actually written in Java. Definitely, at some point, there will be native code (the code written for specific OS, and compiled for specific architecture). This is where there are different JVM distribution for different architecture and OS.

Comment: Many features of the API (such as creating windows and handling files) are based upon native method, which are written in low-level languages such as C.

Comment: you can look at how the java libraries are coded and see for yourself if you want, but it may be hard to understand

Answer (score 3):

If you check the source code of various java classes (e.g. on [docjar](http://www.docjar.com/)) you will eventually notice some method declarations starting with `native` and with no implementation provided (check the [Thread](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html) class). That's where control is passed to some underlying platform-specific code.

Answer (score 1):

The Java runtime library supports many "cool things" natively, however for performant access to windows, file systems, and other OS-native resources Java provides a  mechanism called the Java Native Interface (JNI) which bridges from the JVM to low-level, platform specific libraries.

The sign-post for where the bridge is getting crossed, from the Java perspective, will be the `native` keyword decorating a method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

API classes are designed to give you a clean API to program against.   Think `List`.

Then there are classes fulfilling their part of the contract like `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, which both are lists but have different characteristics.

Things which need the help of the operating system, like writing to a file or drawing on the screen, are written to conform to the API's the operating system provides.  This is usually platform dependent invoked by native code (usually written in C).  Swing - the default Java GUI - is written fully in Java working inside a rectangle provided by the operating system.

When using a modern IDE with a JDK you can always navigate to the classes in the runtime library and see how they actually *do* it.  It is usually much simpler than you think.